# string efficiency of a string insulator using Guard rings

Tags: power-engineering

Does gaurd rings used in power transmissions increases the string efficiency of a string insulator practically?If yes then how.

Answer (score 1):

Guard ring increases the string efficiency of an insulator string practically. If we don't use the guard wire then the voltage across different insulator disks will reduce as we move away from the conductor, thus the highest voltage will appear across the insulator disk which is nearest to the conductor. The guard ring helps in making the voltage distribution across various insulator disks uniform and thus improving the string efficiency.
Their arrangement you can see in the picture below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick [google for "power transmission guard ring"](https://www.google.com/search?q=power+transmission+guard+ring&oq=power+transmission+guard+ring) turned up [this web page](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-guard-ring-used-in-transmission-lines) as the top result & what do you know, it's an effective explanation!

In short, it prevents localized concentration of the E-field from causing a preventable insulator chain breakdown.